# How to push and pop views in Swift UI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I cannot figure out how to push and pop views in Swift UI. In UIKit, it is so simple and I don't know why I can't find a solution to such a simple issue with the new framework. If anyone could help, that would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NavigationLink` inside `NavigationView`.

A tutorial can be found here: [Displaying a detail screen with NavigationLink](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/displaying-a-detail-screen-with-navigationlink).

Links to Apple documentation:

- [NavigationLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink)
- [NavigationView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview)